# An animated shape run over known path

Tags: matlab, tracking, robotics, numerical-integration

I want to simulate a vehicle which tracking known path, what I'm working on is just  an animated shape moving at the path, I wrote my code under matlab I get the square (represent the vehicle)  moving over the path, but, I want to remove the last squares(memories), just want one square every time with right orientation.
anyone please advice me what I can do to achieve that.
my code illustrate what I explained previously:

> ```
> r=0.25;
> t=0:0.1:10;
> A=100;
> yo=A*sin(t);%%desired output position on Y axe
> Voy=diff( yo);
> Vox=ones(1,101);
> Voy(length(Voy)+1)=Voy(length(Voy))
> Vmx=sqrt(Voy.*Voy+Vox.*Vox);
> theta=atan(Voy./Vox);
> %%Speed's equations
> Voy=Vmx.*sin(theta);
> Vox=Vmx.*cos(theta);
> x=0;
> y=0;
> t=0;
> for i=1:1:length(Voy);
> x=Vox(i)*(t);
> y=Voy(i)*0.1;
> pause(0.05)
> t=t+0.1;
> plot(x,y,'--gs',...
> 'LineWidth',2,...
> 'MarkerSize',30,...
> 'MarkerEdgeColor','b',...
> 'MarkerFaceColor',[0.5,0.5,0.5])
> hold on
> end
> ```

Comment: Please make the question more specific. Is it about visualization in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code does what you are looking for:

```
r=0.25;
t=0:0.1:10;
A=100;
yo=A*sin(t);%%desired output position on Y axe
Voy=diff( yo);
Vox=ones(1,101);
Voy(length(Voy)+1)=Voy(length(Voy))
Vmx=sqrt(Voy.*Voy+Vox.*Vox);
theta=atan(Voy./Vox);
%%Speed's equations
Voy=Vmx.*sin(theta);
Vox=Vmx.*cos(theta);
x=0;
y=0;
t=0;
figure;

ph = plot(x,y,'--gs',...
    'LineWidth',2,...
    'MarkerSize',30,...
    'MarkerEdgeColor','b',...
    'MarkerFaceColor',[0.5,0.5,0.5]);

set(gca,'XLim',[0 10]);
set(gca,'YLim',[-2 2]);

for i=1:1:length(Voy);

    x=Vox(i)*(t);
    y=Voy(i)*0.1;
    set(ph,'XData',x);
    set(ph,'YData',y);
    pause(0.05)
    t=t+0.1;
end
```

The trick is, using the handle of the plot for updating its data in the for-loop. This can be done by changing the `XData` and `YData` property of the plot-object:

```
set(ph,'XData',x);
set(ph,'YData',y);
```

Furthermore I would manually set the X- and y-Limits of the axes by

```
set(gca,'XLim',[0 10]);
set(gca,'YLim',[-2 2]);
```

Otherwise it is set dynamically according to the current data, set in the several steps.

Comment: thank you  that solve most of my problem, still want to control the orientation of the square (Robot) over the Line to be more close to the real motion of the robot, so can I achieve that with the last marker.

Comment: that means, you wanna "tilt" the square, or rather control the angle of the square? At the moment you are using a Marker for the visualization. Because it's not possible to adjust marker orientation by function it would be better to use something like `patch` to visualize your robot.